# Connecting old analogue devices to modern digital TV

Tags: video-adapters, signal-processing

I have some old devices (eg. retro gaming units etc.) that connect via an analogue RF antenna connection. What devices are recommended to convert the signal to work with modern digital televisions? (eg. analogue RF to composite/component RCA).

I have seen others use an old VCR as a converter, but I don't want to try source a huge VCR from somewhere just to use as a signal converter.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called a [demodulator](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0011NM17K).  Due to the digital switchover, they are becoming more and more difficult to find, but can still be found if you know what to look for.  It is essentially an NTSC TV tuner, sometimes with only a channel 3/4 tuner, that outputs some other standard output signal such as VGA, composite, Y-Pr-Pb, etc.  Such devices used to sell for less than $20, but are rare enough now that the prices have gone up dramatically.  There are also several on eBay such as [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Professional-RF-Coax-To-RCA-Video-Audio-Demodulator-NTSC-Cable-TV-Tuner-/250465722215?hash=item3a50eb9f67:g:BUYAAOxyepRRvkIz).